# Lucene Return Empty Regex Search Result

Tags: java, regex, solr, lucene

I am working with this unit test of [TestRegexpQuery](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/813ca77250db29116812bc949e2a466a70f969a3/lucene/core/src/test/org/apache/lucene/search/TestRegexpQuery.java) in Lucene, everything works really well but when I added a few extra print statement, I don't quite understand why it doesn't return the document itself.

```
  private int regexQueryNrHits(String regex) throws IOException {
    // RegexpQuery query = new RegexpQuery(newTerm(regex));
    // return searcher.search(query, 5).totalHits;
    RegexpQuery query = new RegexpQuery(newTerm(regex));
    TopDocs result = searcher.search(query, 5);

    // my code to print the result instead of just the counts
    //START
    ScoreDoc[] docs = result.scoreDocs;
    for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : docs) {
      System.out.println(scoreDoc);
      System.out.println(scoreDoc.doc);
      System.out.println(scoreDoc.score);
      System.out.println(scoreDoc.shardIndex);
      System.out.println(searcher.getIndexReader().document(scoreDoc.doc));
    }
    System.out.println("---------");
    // end
    return result.totalHits;
  }
```

This test inserted one document only and this is how the outcome looks and I expect it return either the sentence or the tokens that matched the regular expression but everything looks empty document..

```
---------
doc=0 score=1.0 shardIndex=0
0
1.0
0
Document<>
---------
doc=0 score=1.0 shardIndex=0
0
1.0
0
Document<>
```

Can anyone help me understand what is really going on here regarding the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the field in order to retrieve it.  Indexed, unstored fields can be searched, but won't be returned with results.  Many field constructors take an argument to specify whether it should be stored:

```
doc.add(new TextField("mytext", "some text", Field.Store.YES));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about an instance of lucene document which is "empty".

Empty in your case means that the [toString()-Method](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html#toString%28%29) returns `Document<>`.

This means that the [fields-List](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html#getFields%28%29) is empty. So most possible you have no stored fields.